# How to get rid of empty transparent areas in a PNG image

Tags: ios, png

Im making a game for iOS and I am using `CGRectIntersectsRect` for a lot of it (i.e. when my car hits another car do this). My dilemma is that my car is curved, but it is inside a rectangle, so often times the rectangle will hit the other car but it doesn't show the actual PNG image hitting the other PNG image. How can I make it so the rectangle is only the size of the image, with no transparent space around it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When your car image is no rectangle then you won't succeed with only testing for rectangle intersection.

You can use the rectangle intersection to make a qualified guess on whether there **might** be a collision, and in that case do some more testing on whether there indeed was a collision, like smaller rectangles that approximate the curved shape of your car image, or testing for transparent points.